# Data removal from android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

1. If I log onto whats app using a new device and then delete the app ... will it remove the app , all its data , back ups and pictures from the old device and also remove it from google drive ?

Also would this still work if the device is switched off  or offline

2. If I wish to remote wipe the device would that be possible if I have already disconnected the device from google drive ( for safety reasons ) but it is still active on the find the device ( but won't locate - due to phone possibly running out of battery or offline ?

So if it is offline can it still receive a signal to be remote wiped ?